# how to resolve this 3*3 cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

I've followed the beginner's Rubik's cube solving method and I've arrived at this:

[image: first and second blue and green layers]

[image: second yellow layer is misconceived]

So as you can see, I've succeeded mounting the first layer but within the second one there's a problem with the edge of the yellow/white facets.

Is there a solution to this dilemma?

Comment: These images unfortunately don't give enough context about where pieces are on the cube. In particular, we have no information about the colors on the bottom layer, and I'm not sure what the color scheme is. Would it be possible to fill out one of [these images](http://rubiks-cube-solver.com) and paste a screenshot in? (You don't have to actually use the solver; it won't help much. Just the image will, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Take the cube, Face the side whose second layer is not made towards you , 
and the 1st layer which you made on the top
Now do the following steps

- If the part of the second layer , is on the right side, Then, Move the right side down(counterclockwise); lower layer to the right ; right layer (which you moved down earlier) upwards ie(clockwise this time).
- Then , you will find that, 1st layer which you made, one part is missing , form the 1st layer again, by the same methods by which you made the 1st layer.
- Now the apply the same rule to solve the second layer, which you were trying earlier.

This happens , when all the lower layer edge pieces, have one part same colour as that of the centre of the lower layer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many methods, you can find them allover the net, some experts may resolve your situation in 2-3 seconds, including the brute force method removing first one of the bottom middle cubes, rearrange and set back.